# CSS Div re-sizing according to web browser

Tags: html, css, position, size, division

I have a few divs on my code all of them positioned correctly how i want it. The only problem is that they do not re size when i shrink the page. I want to be able to re size them according to the web browsers size. I do not know exactly how to do it and im worried it might mess up their correct top & left position. All of my divs are currently set as absolute positioning.

Comment: Try `width: 100vw`, if you want your div to fit from the end to the other in the browser. Also, if you have a parent div, just use `width: 100%` to fit it in.

Answer (score 0):

Set their sizes to percent values rather than pixels (I asume that's what you're using)

Comment: Yes you are right, however how would i know a percent of a pixel? You get me lets say i have the top to 300px and the left set as 100px?

Comment: You don't need to know a percent of a pixel... What you're saying is pretty unclear, it would seem you don't understand how the percents work, they are a percent of their parent element, or the element they're inside of, so a div with a width of 5% takes up 5 percent of whatever its inside, so if its in the body, its 5% of the body, or 5% of the entire visible webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Set all divs with percent values.

Or

You can use 'media rules' of css3:

`@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .div-a {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}`

Comment: Yes you are right, however how would i know a percent of a pixel? You get me lets say i have the top to 300px and the left set as 100px.

Comment: You can take in pixel with jQuery.
This way:
`$('#div-a').width();`
`$('#div-a').height();`

Comment: You can use 'media rules' of css3.

`@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .div-a {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}`

You know this?

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 3 options

1. Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/)
2. Use percent values instead of pixels
3. Use vh (view height) and vw (view width). Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7m55nur1/

Note that `width: 75vw;` keeps the div width at 75% of the web browser. Same as `margin-left: 12.5vw` which keeps the margin on the left at 12.5% of the browser size.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out, basically what i did what get the width (lets say it's 300 pixels) and figure out the percent of the page width (in my case is 1900 pixels).
The result would be 15.789473684210526%
putting that exact value worked just fine! As accurate as a pixel. 
I used this tool:**

http://www.onlineconversion.com/percentcalc.htm

**Thank you all for your replies!**