# Using `max-width` with `display: inline-block`

Tags: html, css

I've the following HTML:

```
<div>
 <div id="left" style="display: inline-block; max-width: 500px; vertical-align: top;">
   content left
 </div>
 <div id="right" style="display: inline-block; max-width: 200px; vertical-align: top;">
   content right
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm limiting max width of `#left` to 500px and max width of `#right` to 200px. However when this HTML renders both `#left` and `#right` take exactly as much width as their content (in my case left is 427px and right is like 178px).

Does anyone know how to force `max-width` be respected with `display: inline-block`? If I remove `display: inline-block` and then both left and right render at max-widths but as soon as I put inline-block back left and right divs shrink to approximately their content. Any ideas?

Here's full code:

```
 <div class="body">
      <div id="left">
        content left 
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        content right
     </div>
 </div>

#left {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#right {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't get your point. It seems to be working for me. 
http://jsfiddle.net/uxb5hgtL/

I added `background-color: yellow;` and `background-color: green;` to left and right so you can see.

Comment: Hmm in your example it works. But in my app not works! I debug now. I'll get back to you for more help to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I duplicated my problem

Comment: Add some jsfiddle so i can see it

Comment: See my question I added full code - basically in your jsfuddle make text in left and right smaller (just one or two words). You added too much text so it fills the content. Just remove some text and max-widths wont work.

Comment: Of course it wont work because you are not setting the width of the div, so the div fits it content until it reaches the max-width. If you want the div to have constant div just set the div width, not the max-width

Comment: Thanks. No I don't want constant width. I want it to be fluid for responcive web. How do I make divs fill all available space up to max-div and also make them go smaller if screen is smaller than max-div all fluid, without constant width?

Comment: I've just answered that, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216470/css-div-re-sizing-according-to-web-browser/32216940#32216940